# Cannot create bootable USB with Windows

Tags: linux, usb, window, bootable-media

I have a bootable USB drive that I created using `dd` with Windows 10 downloaded from official Microsoft website and everytime I configure the drive in BIOS as the bootable drive I get an error

```
An operating system wasn’t found. Try disconnecting any drives that don’t contain an operating system.
```

The command I use:

```
sudo dd if=windows10.iso of=/dev/sdf bs=1m status=progress
```

I also tried:

```
sudo dd if=windows10.iso of=/dev/sdf1 bs=1m status=progress
```

I tried using `unetbootin` but that didn't work either (I think there are some issues with it)

I tried erasing everything from the drive, deleting all partitions, formatting, creating a FAT32 partition and adding bootable flag to it but no luck. I tried creating both MBR and GPT partition table but no luck either. I tried it both on Fedora 37 and Macbook and same thing. What am I missing?

```
lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE FSVER LABEL                   UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                                                                             
sdb                                                                                             
├─sdb1 vfat   FAT32                         11AC-A58B                             581.4M     3% /boot/efi
├─sdb2 ext4   1.0                           eb1a62b0-1f8a-4353-a67f-b3f1ab851416  637.5M    28% /boot
└─sdb3 btrfs        fedora_localhost-live   1be3b604-47e4-4fb5-8e9b-aa05dd8bc156  208.3G    10% /home
                                                                                                /
sdc                                                                                             
└─sdc1 ntfs         Filmy, gry, muzyka      96C8335EC8333BB5                                    
sdd                                                                                             
├─sdd1                                                                                          
├─sdd2 ntfs                                 FC00B1A200B16474                                    
└─sdd3                                                                                          
sde                                                                                             
sdf    udf    1.02  CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-GB_DV9 1aab80004d532055                           0   100% /run/media/jedrek/CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-GB_DV9
sr0                                                                                             
zram0                                                                                           [SWAP]
```

`sdf` is my USB drive.

Comment: A small correction to @John 's comment above, the media created with the official Media Creation tool IS bootable, Rufus isn't necessary, you use one or the other, not one after the other as the comment suggests (probably by mistake). That said, the tolls are for Windows only and you're trying to do it from some Linux. **Currently there's no way to do it from Linux with traditional tools including `dd`** because the Microsoft ISO files aren't compliant with the standard since years ago. You can use **MKUSB** in Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives or the multi-boot tool **Ventoy**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the USB and use Ventoy.

> Ventoy formats the USB disk while creating the bootable disk. However, I noticed it failed to do so for an already bootable Linux disk. For this reason, I advise you to format the USB disk before you proceed further.

After downloading and extracting the Ventoy `.tar.gz` file,

> Go inside the extracted folder, and you’ll find a few scripts in it. You need to run one named VentoyWeb.sh.

> Ventoy runs inside a browser. It will give you the URL when you run it. Copy this URL and paste it in a browser. It will open a web page with Ventoy running in it and if the USB is already plugged in, it should recognize it. If not, press the refresh button.

Use the GPT partitioning scheme for an UEFI installation.
There will be two partitions on the disk after hitting install.

- **VTOYEFI**: A small partition for the UEFI files.
- **Ventoy**: A big, empty partition in ExFAT format where you’ll copy the ISO image.

> Copy the ISO image of the Windows 10 into the bigger ExFAT partition on the USB disk.

Proceed with the installation.

Here is the full detailed guide.

[bootable-windows-usb-linux](https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux)

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is mainly that the ISO (UDF actually) contains file (`sources/install.wim`) that is larger than 4G, so you can't use one FAT32 to contain everything so that it can be booted by UEFI. But other than that, you can really just mount the ISO (UDF) file and copy the files to an NTFS partition. If your machine has UEFI firmware by AMI (a.k.a. Aptio), you should be able to UEFI boot from the NTFS partition directly.

---

[`ms-sys`](https://ms-sys.sourceforge.net/) can help you write the necessary boot code to the MBR **and** the boot sector of the NTFS partition.

Make sure you use MBR/DOS-style partition table instead of GPT if you want BIOS boot.

Also, the active flag (sometimes called the boot flag) needs to be set on the NTFS partition.

---

For UEFI, create additionally an FAT32 partition and install a set of grub to it.

```
grub-install --target x86_64-efi --efi-directory $mp --boot-directory $mp --removable
```

where `$mp` is the mountpoint the FAT32 partition. On some distro you might need to run `grub2-install` instead.

Then you can create a `grub.cfg` (under `$mp/grub/`) to chainload what's on the NTFS partition. For example:

```
menuentry 'Windows Setup' {
    search -u ... -s
    chainloader /efi/boot/bootx64.efi
}
```

where `...` should be the volume ID of the NTFS filesystem, which can be found as the UUID with e.g. `lsblk -f`.

Technically either types of partition table can be used for UEFI native boot.

---

P.S. The `dd` approach was never supposed to work for image files that is not specifically prepared with non-optical boot support.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. One note, though. If FAT32 partition couldn't be larger than 4GB then I would've got an error while dd-ing the iso into it but I didn't. Perhaps `dd` doesn't work for ISO images with windows, I always use `dd` to create linux bootable drives and it works.

Comment: The Windows "ISO" file is actually an image of a UDF filesystem, which has nothing to do with FAT32 and kind of why it won't boot when being written to a USB drive. Also, I didn't say FAT32-formatted partition cannot be large than 4G, but a FAT32 *filesystem* cannot contain *file* that is larger than 4G. Linux installation/live "ISO"s are mostly "hybrid images", which are what I was referring to when I said `specifically prepared with non-optical boot support`. They are not *just* ISO9660 / UDF filesystem images, but are also composed of a partition table and a FAT32 filesystem/partition.

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks